# python multiprocess queue with infinity loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, infinite-loop

I create 3 processes and want the function wirte1 to write value 'A,B,C' to queue1 ,and function read1 read value from queue1 and put it to queue2 ,in the same time, function read2 read value from queue2, but value B,C can't read from queue2 in time and the process finished.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue,Manager,Pool,Lock
import os, time, random

#向队列1写数据
def write1(q1,lock):
    lock.acquire()
    for value in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
        print ('Put %s to queue111...%s' % (value,str(os.getpid())))
        q1.put(value)
        time.sleep(1)
    lock.release()

#从队列1读取数据并写入队列2
def read1(q1,q2,lock):
    lock.acquire()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        value=q1.get()
        # if value is None:break
        print('Get %s from queue111.%s' % (value,str(os.getpid())))
        q2.put(value)
        print('Put %s to queue222...%s' % (value,str(os.getpid())))
    lock.release()

def read2(q2,lock):
    lock.acquire()
    while True:
        # if not q2.empty() or not q1.empty():
        time.sleep(2)
        value=q2.get(True)
        print('Get %s from queue222.%s' % (value,os.getpid()))
    lock.release()

if __name__=='__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    # 父进程创建Queue，并传给各个子进程：
    q1 = manager.Queue()
    q2 = manager.Queue()
    lock1 = manager.Lock()
    lock2 = manager.Lock()
    lock3 = manager.Lock()
    start=time.time()
    p = Pool()
    # pw = p.apply_async(write1, args=(q1,lock1,))
    pw = Process(target=write1,args=(q1,lock1,))
    # time.sleep(0.5)
    # pr = p.apply_async(read1, args=(q1,q2,lock2,))
    # pr2 = p.apply_async(read2, args=(q2,lock3))
    pr=Process(target=read1,args=(q1,q2,lock2,))
    pr2 = Process(target=read2,args=(q2,lock3,))

    pw.start()
    pr.start()
    pr2.start()

    # p.close()
    # p.join()
    pw.join()
    pr.terminate()
    pr2.terminate()


    end=time.time()
    # print
    print('finished!!')
    print(end-start)
```

the output is:
    `Put A to queue111...77678 Put B to queue111...77678 Get A from queue111.77680 Put A to queue222...77680 Put C to queue111...77678 Get A from queue222.77681 Get B from queue111.77680 Put B to queue222...77680 Get C from queue111.77680 Put C to queue222...77680 finished!! 3.025238275527954`

Comment: any one can help pls!

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use `terminate` to control a system like this: it **races** with completing the actual work.  Instead, make your loops not be infinite, probably by using a **sentinel** value in each `Queue` (as in one commented-out line).

Comment: I have tried using break in the whileTRUE loop, but it still can't output correct result

Comment: @josephyu: Without seeing the (new) code, no one can help with that.